# Hibernate Envers revision number order

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I used Envers to audit my entities. The DB used is Oracle 11g. For the revision number of the revision entity, I used a oracle sequence. But since the oracle sequence does not guarantee monotonic increasing of each call to nextval, In my revision table, I got something like this,[image]

We can see that the rev number is not monotonically increasing. In the audit table of my entity, I have this:

By chaining the records together with the rev number to form a timeline, I got :

24 --> 1302 --> 1303 **-->** 1355 **-->** 1304 --> 1356 --> 1357 --> 1305 -->1358 --> null

In fact, I have a cluster of 2 servers. They both can persist data into the DB. I suspect that this has relation to the problem of order in revnumber. Because of this problem. Query like MyEntity anEntity = auditReader.find(MyEntity.class, id, revNum) doesn't work because of 
`org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractAuditQuery.java:117)` . I checked the SQL generated by Hibernate, in the where clause

```
 where
    myentity.rev<=?
    and myentity.revtype<>?
    and myentity.id=?
    and (
        myentity.revend>?
        or myentity.revend is null
    )
```

so for the rev number 1356, several audit records are retrieved, for example
1356 --> 1357 and 1305 -->1358  because rev num 1356 is just between the two ends.

How can I solve this problem? I mean to make the rev number monotonically increasing one transaction after another.

**UPDATE**

My revision entity

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
@Table(name = "REV_TABLE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "GENERIC_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SQ_REVISION_ID")
public class Revision {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator ="GENERIC_GENERATOR")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = REV)
    @RevisionNumber
    private long rev;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using all the default envers configuration settings or are you customizing any of those?  If you are customizing some, please update your post to include those.

Comment: @Naros I have updated the question with my revision entity class. Do you have an idea how to adapt my class?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `allocationSize=1` on the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at how the revision number sequence is defined inside the `SequenceIdRevisionEntity` class.  We essentially define it as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "RevisionNumberSequenceGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "RevisionNumberSequenceGenerator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.envers.enhanced.OrderedSequenceGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "table_name", value = "REVISION_GENERATOR"),
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "REVISION_GENERATOR"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
        }
)
@RevisionNumber
private int id;
```

The key is specifying that the `initial_value` and `increment_size` are defined as `1` to avoid the hi-lo gaps you're noticing with your existing sequence definition.